# How to pass function as argument from one function to another?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, socket.io

I want to pass value to callback so i can use into another function, So below consumer is consistently receiving messages that is working, now i want to pass these messages to `io` everytime i receive message in consumer so i can `emit` it to client. So i cannot call consumer function inside `io.connection` How can i get value from consumer using callback and make sure it emits to correct socket ?

app.js

```
consumer.on('message', function(message, callback) {
    logger.log('info', message.value);
    callback(message.value);
});

io.on('connection', function(socket, callback) {
    callback(message.value);
    socket.emit('ditConsumer', message.value);
});
```

clientSocketFactory.js

```
angular.module('loggingApp').factory('socket', function ($rootScope) {
    'use strict';
    var server = 'http://localhost:3000';
    var socket = io.connect(server,{'forceNew': true });
    function socket_reconnect() {
        socket.connect();
    };
        return {
            on: function (eventName, callback) {
                socket.on(eventName, function () {
                    var args = arguments;
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    });
                });
            },
            emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
                socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
                    var args = arguments;
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        if (callback) {
                            callback.apply(socket, args);
                        }
                    });
                })
            },
            disconnect: function () {
                socket.disconnect();
            },
            reconnect: function () {
                socket_reconnect();
            },
        };

});
```

ctrl.js

```
$scope.event = [];
 socket.on('ditConsumer',function (data) {
        $scope.event.push(data);
    });
```

Comment: What is missing in your problem description is how you know which socket you want to `socket.emit()` to when consumer gets a message.  Remember, there are many different sockets that have connected to the server.  This question cannot be answered without knowing that.

Comment: So you are saying problem is more of client side , i have one factory that will be using for all socket connections from the server as i added into my question.

Comment: No, that isn't what I said at all.  I just said, if you're going to send to a socket from consumer, you have to know which socket to send to.  I'm not an angular guy so I won't comment on angular stuff.

Comment: First  i think i need to figure it out how can i get consumer message value to io then second i will make sure its emitting it to right socket, because if i send hard coded data from io its emitting it to client being said in my understanding connection is established, its just the matter to pass correct values to io.